# Filtering nested array in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar menu.
I would like to hide some paths, based on user's role.
Here I have ROUTES like this:

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  {
    path: '/overview',
    title: 'Overview',
    type: 'link',
    icontype: 'search'
  },
  {
    path: '/loyalty',
    title: 'Loyalty',
    type: 'sub',
    icontype: 'loyalty',
    collapse: 'loyalty',
    children: [
      { path: 'programs', title: 'Programs', ab: 'P', icontype: 'accessibility' },
      { path: 'members', title: 'Members', ab: 'M', icontype: 'group_add' },
      { path: 'segments', title: 'Segments', ab: 'S', icontype: 'data_usage' },
      { path: 'emailautomation', title: 'Email automation', ab: 'EA', icontype: 'mail' }
    ]
  },
```

... etc

My sidebar appears like as fallows:

```
this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);
```

I'd like to filter children array, taking into consideration user's role.

How can I filter these ROUTES to hide, for example, path 'programs' ?

Comment: What's the criteria are you trying to filter by?

Comment: Seems you're looking for [Route Guards(Angular Doc)](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Comment: @ulmas lt's say, if user has a role 'user' I would like to generate side menu without path 'programs'. So, children array should look like [ 
      { path: 'members', title: 'Members', ab: 'M', icontype: 'group_add' },
      { path: 'segments', title: 'Segments', ab: 'S', icontype: 'data_usage' },
      { path: 'emailautomation', title: 'Email automation', ab: 'EA', icontype: 'mail' }]

Comment: @Chenna I don't think so ... Route Guards wont give me the access to this route, but it still be rendered in the side menu

Comment: @ulmas i just want to loop through ROUTES array, find children array and filter it, hiding some objects

Comment: This question is related to Angular right? or AngularJS??

Comment: @P.Shustenko if you simply not render a URL, if a user with limited access knows the URL, they can still type it in, and they will be able to access the application. Is this how you want to design your application?

Comment: Even if user knows the URL route guard will block access to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
children: [
  { path: 'programs', title: 'Programs', ab: 'P', icontype: 'accessibility', role: ['admin'] },
  { path: 'members', title: 'Members', ab: 'M', icontype: 'group_add', role: ['admin', 'editor'] },
  { path: 'segments', title: 'Segments', ab: 'S', icontype: 'data_usage' }, // items with no role are public
  { path: 'emailautomation', title: 'Email automation', ab: 'EA', icontype: 'mail' }
]
```

I don't know how and where you keep your user roles, so let's say there is a field in the component that user roles are there:

```
userRoles: string[] = ['admin'];
```

In your view:

```
<ul class="nav"> 
  <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let childitem of menuitem.children" class="nav-item"
    [class.d-none]="childitem.role && !userRoles.includes(childitem.role)"> 
    <a [routerLink]="[menuitem.path, childitem.path]" class="nav-link"> 
      <i class="material-icons">{{ childitem.icontype }}</i> 
      <span class="sidebar-normal">{{ childitem.title }}</span> 
    </a> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any method to block access just by looping through routes, but I hope this will be approach useful

> In SideBar Component

```js
checkAccess(): boolean { //write your own custom
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userrole') == 'admin'){ // write your own custom user role check
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> To remove User Links in your sidebar UI

```html
<a [routerLink]=['/programs'] *ngIf="checkAccess()">Programs</a>
```

You can additionally block access from Router Level itself

> In routing module

```js
{
   path: 'programs', 
   title: 'Programs',
   ab: 'P', icontype: 'accessibility', 
   canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard],
   //canActivateChlid: [AuthorizeGuard]
},
```

> In Authorize Guard

```js
canActivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('userrole') == 'admin'){ // write your own custom user role check
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is good approach. But I don't have separate links in my sidebar component.. I have *ngFor like this.

<ul class="nav">
          <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let childitem of menuitem.children" class="nav-item">
            <a [routerLink]="[menuitem.path, childitem.path]" class="nav-link">
              <i class="material-icons">{{ childitem.icontype }}</i>
              <span class="sidebar-normal">{{ childitem.title }}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

Comment: then you can add `*ngIf="hasAccess(menuitem)"` in `<li>` element and in your component file `hasAccess(menuItem)` which returns `boolean` value. By doing this only the links the which user has permission will be visible.